# Источники обучения JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Короче, начал учить JS и хочу попросить у знающих людей хорошие источники для обучения. Отдельная благодарность за книги или курсы с заданиями. При этом, пожалуйста, скидывайте как про чистый JS, так и про его фреймворки. Желательно, с постепенным повышением сложности. Всем огромное спасибо

Comment: Зачем вам фреймворк если вы не знаете основы языка? Я начинал с jQuery и потом очень сильно огорчился своими знаниями. На нативе всё выходило лучше и понятнее. И только после небольшого вхождения в ЯП уже заинтересовался его фреймворками для более лучшего написания кода.

Comment: Да, я знаю, что все сразу понять невозможно, поэтому попросил с постепенным повышением сложности:)